# How to wait for a website to totally load before displaying it on the screen (ionic app development)?

Tags: android, javascript, css, ios

I am developing an ionic mobile application. I would like to load a website and display it on the screen when it is totally loaded. While waiting for the website to load, I would like to have a background picture and a spinner indicating to the user that he/she has to wait. 
Below is the code that I used to load the website (in the app.js file). However, I am not sure where the command should be placed exactly.

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    window.open('https://www.google.com', '_self', 'location=no');
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
      }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
     }
  });
})
```

In the index.html file:

```
<ion-pane>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title" aligh=center >Starter</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content> 
  <ion-spinner icon="spiral"></ion-spinner>
  </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

Do I need a controller to do the task (To know when the website will be ready and display it)?

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). You can flag your question and ask a moderator to migrate it.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can write in

`$(window).load(function(){ ... });`